# Query the parent table from child table in laravel

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel, web

I don't know if the term or title is right but here is what i want to achieve.
I want to get the data of the parent from child table:

lets say **Location** hasmany **Store**, and **Store** hasmany **Products**

My goal is how i can get the data of location thru the product data?

In native php i can achieve this by using join sql query. How about in laravel?

Comment: you can define this relationship inside your model , see documentation for more info = https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using eloquent

1:in your product modal create a relationship with store something like this

```
    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class, 'store_id');
    }
```

2: now create a relationship with location and store in your store modal

```
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Location::class, 'location_id');
    }
```

3: now when you want to get product with location you can do something like this

```
   public function getProduct()
{
  $items=Products::with('store.location')->get();
}
```